# Is it safe to remove old Chrome extension versions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I just looked how I can slim down my home directory and noticed that Chrome's `.config` directory is unusually big. More than 600 MB in my case.

[image]

Most of it is occupied by by the Google Play Music extension (fahmaaghhglfmonjliepjlchgpgfmobi). As you can see in the screenshot, the directory contains a lot of versions which accumulate to a lot of wasted disk space. All other extensions have a maximum of two version (although the reason for this may be that they just don't have a lot of updates).

I don't think it's unreasonable to keep one or two versions in case the newer versions mess things up. But I would like to get rid of most of these unnecessary versions.

Can I just delete them or will Chrome act up? Is there a (non-)secret way to do it from the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

If you have no non-recoverable strings attached to those extensions then I would tell you to uninstall all the versions of the extension (even the latest) and fresh install it. If you have some non-recoverable strings attached then just delete. If Chrome can't find em, Chrome can't run 'em. That's because Chrome doesn't even know what should be there. Look [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/140464/how-to-manually-uninstall-a-globally-installed-chrome-extension/) and [here](http://www.timeatlas.com/uninstall-chrome-extensions/%20%22Productivity%20Portfolio) for instructions if you have Windows. The first one is recommended. Looking at your screenshot, the tale is same for Linux. Help for Linux is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82186/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-google-chrome-and-chromium). And your screen shot yells Linux. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hm, none of these links look helpful. The second link doesn't work. Yes, I'm on Linux. What is an "attached non-recoverable string"? I guess I'll just do the reinstall way but still it would be nice to know whether the extraneous versions can simply be removed without corrupting the chrome profile.

Comment: @musiKk It was a metaphor for something like data or feelings (some people do, I don't) which are attached to that extension or you. Not some computer term. And I tried deleting mine. No problem at all. "Chrome doesn't even know what should be there." It just runs whatever is there. So just delete them. BTW, should I include these explanations in the answer?